# How to change the output of default maven project

Tags: maven

i created a simple maven project using command prompt.I used the following command:-

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DgroupId=com.companyname.bank 
-DartifactId=consumerBanking 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

Even after changing the content of App.java file, I am getting the same Hello World ! as output.

Can anyone help me to come out of it.
thanks.

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Please be specific in what you intend to do.

Comment: I mean to say after using the above command, maven automatically creates a project which gives the output as Hello World by using the command-java packagename.App     Now I modified the code of self created App.java in src folder,  in which i wrote "maven project" in S.O.P . after compiling and running the App.java again ,the output remains the same as "hello world!".why it is happening so

Answer (score 0):

After changing any content, you need to rebuild the project. Use the command `mvn clean install -U` to build the project again and then run your main class. This should solve your problem.